# invalid type for key fromUser, expected map, but got *_User

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Have error when saving `PFObject`:

> invalid type for key fromUser, expected map, but got *_User

```
private func makeFriendRequest(toUser: PFUser) {
    var friendRequest = PFObject(className: "FriendRequest")
    friendRequest["fromUser"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    friendRequest["toUser"] = toUser
    friendRequest["status"] = "pending"
    friendRequest.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            println("Error for makeFriendRequest: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }else {
            println("Request successfully made")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of field is fromuser  ? seems you have custom object named map.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan It's of PFUser type.

Comment: Check fromUser in FriendReuest Class .If it were PFUser then no error would be there .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped `FriendRequest` class in app settings, created new and set up `fromUser` and `toUser` as a pointers to `User` class.

After that it works well.